# how to convert excel column data to row data

Tags: excel

I have a column like this

[image: present data]

but I want to convert like this

[image: want to convert this format]

how can I do this in ms excel?

Answer (score 0):

With data in **C1**, in **D1** enter:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C1,"&","&amp;"),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With <kbd>ExcelO365</kbd> you can try-

```
=TRANSPOSE(MID(C1,{1,4,7,10},1))
```

[image]

If you do not have `Excel365` then try below formula.

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($C$1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),ROW(1:1))
```

<kbd>Note:</kbd> `FILTERXML()` function is available on `Excel2013` and higher.